# making "gnome-system-monitor" a custom shortcut "ctrl+alt+del" like windows "Task Manager" isn't working

Tags: shortcut-keys, system-monitor

I went to "System Settings", "keyboard", "shortcuts", "custom shortcuts", I added a custom shortcut and called it "task manager" in the "command line:" I typed "gnome-system-monitor", and I gave it the command, "ctrl+alt+del", I apply that and close it.  Then I try it and get NOTHING...... why??

Comment: Does it work in gnome shell but not in unity? Maybe the shortcut is taken by something else... Try in gnome-shell to bind /usr/bin/gnome-system-monitor to some non-obvious shortcuts !

Answer (score 6):

In fact, you cannot use `Ctrl+Alt+Del` as your shortcut, because it is taken by a logout message, as I just checked:

[image: logout dialog]

In order to enable it, you have to go to the keyboard shortcuts you went before, and disable that shortcut or give it another key binding:

[image: keyboard shortcut]

Then, you will be able to add your custom shortcut.
In order for this to work for sure, you have to completely disable the other shortcut:

[image: disabling the shortcut]

In order to do this, select the shortcut and press the `Backspace` button.

Now, you have to go to the *Custom Shortcuts* section and add a new shortcut, containing the following:

[image: new shortcut creation]

Name: Whatever relevant

Command: gnome-system-monitor

I did this and it works fine in Ubuntu 12.04!

Comment: I already disabled the "logout" option because i had to, but it still isn't doing anything when I hit "ctrl+alt+delete"

Comment: Please check my edited answer!

Answer (score 2):

In the command-line(space for the command) you have to enter

/usr/bin/gnome-system-monitor

### How to find the command-

In linux to find a command to exicute a particular program you have to enter in the terminal the following command-

whereis

For e.g for the above example you will get a screen like this when you put

whereis gnome-system-monitor

[image: whereis]

the 1st line "/usr/bin/programname" is the command you have to put/use/execute.

then add the key-binding(use something else like alt+cltr+menu.the one you used is assigned to something else) and save.It will work. :)

### How to add in settings-

Open System Settings > Keyboard >Shortcuts tab > custom shortcuts >"+" button > in the name "System Monitor" or anything you want >in the Command space "/usr/bin/gnome-system-monitor" (all small case) > apply.

[image: key bindimg]

then click on the space where "Disabled" is writen and press the kay combination(other than alt+cltr+del.it is assigned to log out) for e.g as seen in picture, i had assigned alt+cltr+menu(the right-click menu button on the  right of space bar)

if you still want to assign alt+cltr+del as the key binding,change the one for log out in the "system" option there and then assign it to this.

Comment: forgive me cause I'm a newbie with Ubuntu, coming from windows recently. I tried entering "/usr/bin/gnome-system-monitor" (without quotes) in the command line and it didn't work, but I'm probably misunderstanding you.

Comment: I'll give you a photographic tutorial step by step as another answer wait. :)

Comment: ok, awesome! i appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

In the default configuration of Ubuntu 12.04 (do not know in others) `Ctrl+Alt+Del` is set to close session shortcut. Make sure you have disable this or changed it to another shortcut.

(Sorry it is in Spanish, its the first line. It is deactivated)

[image]

Then you can set your custom shortcut to `Ctrl+Alt+Del`:

(The last one)

[image]

If it does not work, try to restart your session (Not sure if reboot is needed) and check that the values are still the ones you set.

Comment: I disabled the logout command, and restarted my computer, my new shortcut keys are still there and it still doesn't do anything when I try those keys.

Comment: What release are you using?

Comment: it's Ubuntu 12.04, i have gnome advanced settings installed, maybe that has something to do with it??

Comment: Advance settings doesn't have to do anything about it. Try to set a different combination set to the same command to make sure where is the problem. Also re-check the command its exactly 'gnome-system-monitor'

Comment: I think you shouldn't have posted those screen shots.