# Measure amount of traffic in Ubuntu in GBs?

Tags: networking, traffic

My university internet connections such as Eduroam and Aalto Open are extremely poor so I use prepaid-services, less lag. Now I may run out of prepaid time so how can I measure the amount of traffic consumed in Ubuntu?

I am actually using Debian but probably no difference in traffic -monitoring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use System monitor to see the traffic used in a single session. Use `gnome-system-monitor` to open it in a terminal.

You a totalistic view of usage, you can use `ipac-ng`. Install it with the command

```
sudo apt-get install ipac-ng
```

[Here is a good guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMonitorInternetTrafficTotals) about usage of this software.

Alternatively, You can also use `vnstat`. Install it wit the command:

```
sudo apt-get install vnstat
```

To start vnstat cron job, you would use this simple command:

```
sudo vnstat -u -i eth0
```

Replace `eth0` with the actual interface for you. It is `eth1` for me. This job will run every five minutes measure and update the usage data. At any given time you can use `vnstat` command to see the usage.

[A good guide about using vnstat is here](http://www.4geeksfromnet.com/2009/04/graphical-bandwidth-monitor-for-ubuntu.html). You can also check [Ubuntu manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/vnstat.1.html)
 page for vnstat

Comment: ...where is that?

Comment: @hhh see the edit

Comment: +1 thank you, solved ...could not find `ipac-ng` but the gnome -thing worked.

Comment: ...still 6 minutes waiting...

Comment: +1 Good answer. [Here's a way](http://askubuntu.com/q/138608/12864) to make a keyboard short-cut for launching System Monitor.