# monitor internet usage

Tags: networking, monitoring

I use vnstat to monitor internet data usage over wlan interface but since I also stream videos from my file server...the results are inaccurate. Is there any way to seperate data downloaded from internet from data streamed from file server in vnstat? or any program that will let me monitor monthly internet usage only (ignoring the data usage produced by the streaming)?

Comment: closely related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/194538/measure-amount-of-traffic-in-ubuntu-in-gbs - ipac-ng is mentioned in the answer there.

Comment: ipac-ng is not in repos

Comment: tried to compile ipac-ng from source. there's some issue with libgdbm...not compiled in :( ipac-ng looked promising

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wireshark [image: Install wireshark]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wireshark) to do this, but you will have a lot to learn about its usage.