# Why is custom shortcut Ctrl+Alt+Delete special and not working?

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts

This question is pretty much a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138608/making-gnome-system-monitor-a-custom-shortcut-ctrlaltdel-like-windows-tas). However I'm starting this question, because all the answers in the other question seem to focus on how to setup a custom shortcut for gnome-system-monitor, while the actual question is *why* does it not work?

That is I make a custom shortcut to launch `gnome-system-monitor`. I make sure that the System Log out is disabled (which is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> by default). When I bind the gnome-system-monitor shortcut to anything else (say <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>), everything is fine and the system monitor starts.

But nothing happens when I assign it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

This is in Ubuntu 14.04 and I now this shortcut worked in previous versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting it using Compiz, after disabling it from System Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts tab:

1. Install `ccsm`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Run it and enable *Commands* plugin
3. Set it the command in *Commands* tab & shortcut in *Key Bindings* tab

   [image: compiz set command shortcut - 1]

   [image: compiz set command shortcut - 2]

Actually, setting custom shortcut from System Setting works too for me. Custom shortcuts are handled by `media-keys` plugin from `unity-settings-daemon` try reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-settings-daemon
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! do you have any thoughts on why this works, but setting it from keyboards settings does not? should I file a bug report or something?

Comment: Actually, setting custom shortcut from System Setting works too for me. Custom shortcuts are handled by *media-keys* plugin from *unity-settings-daemon* try reinstall it `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-settings-daemon`

Comment: That's it! now it works by setting it in the keyboard system settings too.