# Is there a way to start up System Monitor from the terminal?

Tags: 16.04, system

I am trying to start system monitor from the terminal but when I type `system monitor` it says:

```
No command 'system' found, did you mean:
 Command 'systemd' from package 'systemd' (main)
 Command 'system3' from package 'simh' (universe)
```

Comment: You can add a short cut key for System Monitor: http://askubuntu.com/questions/138608/making-gnome-system-monitor-a-custom-shortcut-ctrlaltdel-like-windows-tas

Comment: you want to run this command `gnome-system-monitor`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command is:

```
gnome-system-monitor
```

If you want to know what application command, navigate to `/usr/share/applications`, then right click on the application's icon to select "Properties" in the context menu.

[image]